# How to display max value from row subtotals? (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Below is a simplified chart in Excel for ease of Q&A.

What I have is a matrix in Power BI that shows the average value as a subtotal.

The desired output is highlighted in yellow, which contains the greatest average from all columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With DAX Mesaures

```
_avgA :=
CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( factTbl[typeA] ), ALL ( factTbl ) )

_avgB :=
CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( factTbl[typeB] ), ALL ( factTbl ) )

_avgC :=
CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( factTbl[typeC] ), ALL ( factTbl ) )

_greatestAvg :=
MAXX (
    UNION ( ROW ( "allAvg", [_avgA] ), ROW ( "avg", [_avgB] ), ROW ( "avg", [_avgC] ) ),
    [allAvg]
)

_A :=
VAR _1 =
    SUM ( factTbl[typeA] )
RETURN
    IF ( HASONEVALUE ( factTbl[ID] ), _1, [_avgA] )

_B :=
VAR _1 =
    SUM ( factTbl[typeB] )
RETURN
    IF ( HASONEVALUE ( factTbl[ID] ), _1, [_avgB] )

_C :=
VAR _1 =
    SUM ( factTbl[typeC] )
VAR _2 =
    IF ( HASONEVALUE ( factTbl[ID] ), _1, [_greatestAvg] )
RETURN
    _2
```

[image: Solution]